# Mysql - Can't get correct rows with max value from an alias value

Tags: mysql, group-by, max

I have a price table with all prices for my products.
A product can have different prices depends of : the country, the customer group, the currency, an interval of date ...

Here my table "commerce_product_price_index" with an exemple : 1 product with 2 prices.

```
+----+------------+-------------------+-------------+------------+------------+---------+------------+------------+-------+
| id | product_id | customer_group_id | currency_id | country_id | geozone_id | user_id | time_from  | time_to    | price |
+----+------------+-------------------+-------------+------------+------------+---------+------------+------------+-------+
| 1  | 1          | 0                 | 0           | 0          | 0          | 0       | 1488632584 | 1646348400 | 500   |
| 2  | 1          | 0                 | 3           | 19         | 7          | 0       | 1488632584 | 1646348400 | 700   |
+----+------------+-------------------+-------------+------------+------------+---------+------------+------------+-------+
```

For each rows I calculate a "score" depends of : the country_id, geozone_id, user_id, currency_id .... These values are taken before when a the customer is logged so don't mind of this.

Example of my request to calculate the score (I don't put conditions WHERE to simplify the example):

```
SELECT `cppi`.*, 
IF (1488788495 >= `time_from` AND 1488788495 <= `time_to`, 1, 0) + 
IF (`customer_group_id` = 2, 2, 0) + IF (`geozone_id` = 7, 4, 0) + 
IF (`country_id` = 19, 8, 0) + IF (`currency_id` = 3, 16, 0)+ 
IF (`user_id` = 0, 32, 0) AS score 
FROM `commerce_product_price_index` AS `cppi`
```

So now I have a new field in my results => "Score".

```
+----+------------+-------------------+-------------+------------+------------+---------+------------+------------+-------+----------+
| id | product_id | customer_group_id | currency_id | country_id | geozone_id | user_id | time_from  | time_to    | price | score    |
+----+------------+-------------------+-------------+------------+------------+---------+------------+------------+-------+----------+
| 1  | 1          | 0                 | 0           | 0          | 0          | 0       | 1488632584 | 1646348400 | 500   | 33       |  
| 2  | 1          | 0                 | 3           | 19         | 7          | 0       | 1488632584 | 1646348400 | 700   | 61       |
+----+------------+-------------------+-------------+------------+------------+---------+------------+------------+-------+----------+
```

The first row have a score => 33

The second row have a score  => 61

So I decided from this request to get the rows with the max score.

```
SELECT `ccpi_max_score`.*, MAX(score) AS max_score 
FROM (
  SELECT `cppi`.*, 
  IF (1488788495 >= `time_from` AND 1488788495 <= `time_to`, 1, 0) +
  IF (`customer_group_id` = 2, 2, 0) + 
  IF (`geozone_id` = 7, 4, 0) + 
  IF (`country_id` = 19, 8, 0) + 
  IF (`currency_id` = 3, 16, 0)+ 
  IF (`user_id` = 0, 32, 0) AS score 
  FROM `commerce_product_price_index` AS `cppi`
) AS ccpi_max_score 
GROUP BY product_id
```

Here the result: It returns one row but with wrong price. I get the row with the price "500" instead of the row with the price "700".

```
+----+------------+-------------------+-------------+------------+------------+---------+------------+------------+-------+----------+-----------------+
| id | product_id | customer_group_id | currency_id | country_id | geozone_id | user_id | time_from  | time_to    | price | score    | max_score       |
+----+------------+-------------------+-------------+------------+------------+---------+------------+------------+-------+----------+-----------------+
| 1  | 1          | 0                 | 0           | 0          | 0          | 0       | 1488632584 | 1646348400 | 500   | 33       | 61              |
+----+------------+-------------------+-------------+------------+------------+---------+------------+------------+-------+----------+-----------------+
```

I think it's a problem with the GROUP BY. But I'm new with SQL and I don't where is my mistake.

I created a fiddle => http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a25f9/4/0

Thank you.

Comment: you won't need GROUP_BY again when you already have MAX

Comment: Hello @AKZhang. If I remove GROUP BY I have the same result.

Comment: problem is,, you need write all column name..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
commerce_product_price_index P
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            product_id,
            MAX(
                IF (1488788495 >= `time_from` AND 1488788495 <= `time_to`, 1, 0) +
                IF (`customer_group_id` = 2, 2, 0) +
                IF (`geozone_id` = 7, 4, 0) +
                IF (`country_id` = 19, 8, 0) +
                IF (`currency_id` = 3, 16, 0)+
                IF (`user_id` = 0, 32, 0)
            ) AS score
        FROM commerce_product_price_index
        GROUP BY product_id
    ) SM
    ON P.product_id = SM.product_id
    AND (
        IF (1488788495 >= P.`time_from` AND 1488788495 <= P.`time_to`, 1, 0) +
        IF ( P.`customer_group_id` = 2, 2, 0) +
        IF ( P.`geozone_id` = 7, 4, 0) +
        IF ( P.`country_id` = 19, 8, 0) +
        IF ( P.`currency_id` = 3, 16, 0)+
        IF ( P.`user_id` = 0, 32, 0)
    ) = SM.score
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT product_id,customer_group_id,currency_id,country_id,geozone_id,user_id,time_from, time_to,price,max(score) as max_score
FROM (
  SELECT `cppi`.*, 
  IF (1488788495 >= `time_from` AND 1488788495 <= `time_to`, 1, 0) +
  IF (`customer_group_id` = 2, 2, 0) + 
  IF (`geozone_id` = 7, 4, 0) + 
  IF (`country_id` = 19, 8, 0) + 
  IF (`currency_id` = 3, 16, 0)+ 
  IF (`user_id` = 0, 32, 0) AS score 
  FROM `commerce_product_price_index` AS `cppi`
) AS ccpi_max_score 
GROUP BY product_id
```

You need to rewrite all column and can't use `.*` except the max is some `unique_id` which can be join to table

Comment: Same result I got the row with the wrong price. Perhaps I have to make again a subselect.

Comment: as i seen your quest. Your query to select max already correct. just the data related with data max is wrong

Comment: I have put the result of your query as a answer above your query. Thx.

Comment: I have put a fiddle => http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a25f9/2/0. And you can look, the result is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

@AKZhang Here the result for your solution.

```
+------------+-------------------+-------------+------------+------------+---------+------------+------------+-------+------------+
| product_id | customer_group_id | currency_id | country_id | geozone_id | user_id | time_from  | time_to    | price | max_score  |
+------------+-------------------+-------------+------------+------------+---------+------------+------------+-------+------------+
| 1          | 0                 | 0           | 0          | 0          | 0       | 1488632584 | 1646348400 | 500   | 61         |
+------------+-------------------+-------------+------------+------------+---------+------------+------------+-------+------------+
```